# "max allowed size 128000 bytes, actual size of encoded class scala" error in akka remoting

Tags: serialization, akka, akka-cluster, akka-remoting

I want to use Akka Remoting to exchange message over network between actors, but for large String message i got the following error:

```
akka.remote.OversizedPayloadException: Discarding oversized payload 
sent to Actor :: max allowed size 128000 bytes
, actual size of encoded class scala.
```

How can i fix this limitation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I add the following configuration and now everything is ok:

```
akka {

  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
    maximum-payload-bytes = 30000000 bytes
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
      message-frame-size =  30000000b
      send-buffer-size =  30000000b
      receive-buffer-size =  30000000b
      maximum-frame-size = 30000000b
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just be careful increasing this limit too high. your sockets could get blocked and your heartbeats might fail.

Comment: With Artery this setting is now `akka.remote.artery.advanced.maximum-frame-size`